# Столкновение коллайдеров в unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Приветствую! Подскажите, как сделать чтобы при столкновении двух объектов, жизнь отнималась у игрока только один раз. Нигде не могу найти этого в интернете.
На данный момент, когда враг сталкивается с игроком, отнимаются сразу все жизни.
Столкновение отслеживается через триггер. При срабатывании функции Death() происходит сразу снятие всех жизней, а мне надо чтобы происходило только один раз. Буду очень признателен за помощь!

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.name == "Player")
    {


        if (scared == true)
        {
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
            _timeToScare = repeat_time;
            InitializeGhost();
            pacman.UpdateScore();

        }
        else {

                Death();

        }
           }
        }
public void Death() {


    death = true;
    animat.SetBool("isDeath", true);
    characterController.enabled = false;
    Weypoint(false);
    Invoke("ResetScenes", 3);

        gm.LoseLife();

    if (gm.lives <= 0) {

        gm.GameOverMenuScreenTrue();

    }

}
```

Comment: По приведенному коду пока сказать мало что можно. Возможно где-то еще вызывается этот метод. Например косяк может быть в самом `LoseLife()` или его вызов тоже может быть еще где-то... Я бы советовал это проверить. И более того - воспользоваться отладкой

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Функция LoseLife() - это просто отнимание жизни.
public void LoseLife()
    {
        lives--;
        LoseLifeText();
    }

Дело в том что когда враг и игрок находятся рядом их колладейры все время взаимодествуют , и видимо поэтому происходит сразу отнимание всех жизней. Так вот я не могу понять как мне сделать , чтобы при это происходило снятие жизни только один раз. 
Может по времени как-то отсрочить, может есть какие то еще способы.

Comment: Ну как грязный хак можно завести таймер `float coolTimer` которое будет хранить время, через которой может сработать отнимание жизни  при триггировании...... заводить таймер...при триггере смотреть если он еще не истек - то отнимание не делать..... а если истекло время - то рестартить время и вычитать жизнь.......но это очень грязно... надо бы скорее посмотреть что ты делаешь, и почему объекты постоянно  хаотично контактируют. Возможно тебе нужен совсем другой вариант

Comment: А ты мог бы глянуть и подсказать? Может даже за какую то копеечку помочь. Я бы кинул исходник куда-то в личку.

Comment: Трюк с тайм аутом для отнимания здоровья - не такой уж и хак, на самом деле. Всё полностью зависит от геймплейной задачи, если ситуация с постоянным столкновением вполне возможна с точки зрения игры - то это вполне логичный и правильный способ отнимания здоровья. А автору вопроса я бы посоветовал немного упорядочить код, не очень правильно, когда здоровье теряется в методе `Death()`. Да и судя по коду, другого поведения кроме как моментальной смерти быть не может, ибо стейт `death=true` включается если НЕ  `scared `, что за scared - пока секрет

Comment: Ты сначала проверь, что у тебя OnTriggerEnter больше 1 раза за кадр для одного объекта не вызывается, можно просто написать Debug.Log(other);  А то, возможно, там какие нибудь NavMeshAgent перемещает, потом по transform, и поверх всего этого еще rigidbody который не kinematic, и получаешь кашу на этапе симуляции физики(transform сюда дернет, физика пересчитает, сместит в другое и т.д.) , и получаешь несколько коллизий/триггеров за кадр.